# Ksoap2, asp.net c#, tempuri.org eliminated, but error : expected: START_TAG {http://schemas..., why"?

Tags: android, asp.net, web-services, ksoap

In my new asp.net webservice project that reply to android app, I eliminated (replaced) tempuri.org with my service and link to my site, also ksoap2 code is perfect from another running project, but I see this error :

```
expected: START_TAG {http://schemas...
```

There is many replies for this error in many conditions like sitemap reading and other, but my case is different, Once I faced it before and solved, but can't remember how? I change android Url to another web service , and it work fine. What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to tempuri.org used server side. When I changed it to my domain , the problem solved.
[change tempuri.org in web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23172937/ksoap2-asynctask-propertyinfo-not-recevied-to-webservice-why?noredirect=1#comment35661957_23172937)